# Django : Can I Pre-fill forms with a model instance datas in form.py?

Tags: python, django, django-views

i've seen a way to do what I want in the views.py file, but as I'm probably going to use the form in several different places, and because I believe it belongs more in forms.py,  I was wondering if and how I could pre-fill my form with the datas already stored in the database for one particular user without modifying the views. Seeing what I tried will speak for itself :

models.py :

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='details')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    dpt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    cplt_add = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py :

```
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self):

        for field in self.fields:

            user_infos = Customers.objects.get(pk=request.user.details.id)
            initial_value = user_infos.field
            field(initial=initial_value)


    def clean_form(self):

        ...


    class Meta:

        model = Customers
        fields = ['city', 'adress', 'dpt', 'cplt_add', 'phone']
        widgets = {
            'city': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form_input',
                'placeholder': 'Ville'}),
            'dpt': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form_input',
                'placeholder': 'Département'}),
            'adress': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form_input',
                'placeholder': 'Adresse'}),
            'cplt_add': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form_input',
                'placeholder': "Complément d'adresse"}),
            'phone': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form_input',
                'placeholder': 'Téléphone'}),
            }
```

This code, sadly but without big surprise, returns :

> 'CustomerForm' object has no attribute 'fields'

Any advice on how to do this with good practice methodology ?

Comment: Can you share the view? Typically you can construct the form like `CustomerForm(instance=my_instance)`

Comment: You should also call `super().__init__(..)` first, since this will construct the `self.fields`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You tackle the problem at the wrong level: Django already has support for this, and writing it in the `__init__` yourself is *not* a good idea (except for some specific *edge-* and *corner cases*).

You can thus remove the `__init__` override from the `ModelForm`:

```
# app/forms.py

class CustomerForm(ModelForm):

    # remove the __init__ override

    class Meta:
        model = Customers
        fields = ['city', 'adress', 'dpt', 'cplt_add', 'phone']
        widgets = {
            'city': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form_input',
                'placeholder': 'Ville'}),
            'dpt': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form_input',
                'placeholder': 'Département'}),
            'adress': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form_input',
                'placeholder': 'Adresse'}),
            'cplt_add': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form_input',
                'placeholder': "Complément d'adresse"}),
            'phone': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form_input',
                'placeholder': 'Téléphone'}),
            }
```

In the view (or somewhere else where you want to construct the form), we can then pass the instance through the `instance=` parameter of the constructor:

```
# app/views.py

def my_view(request):
    customer=Customers.objects.get(pk=request.user.details.id)
    my_form = CustomerForm(instance=customer)
    # ...
    # return HttpResponse object
```

Django will then ensure that the values are filled in the correct forms (as if it were the `initial` values). If you provide both `initial` values and an `instance`, the `initial`s take precendence as described in the [documentation on the **`ModelForm`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values):

> As with regular forms, it's possible to specify initial data for forms by specifying an `initial` parameter when instantiating the form. Initial values provided this way will **override both initial values from the form field and values from an attached model instance**.

Comment: Ho i didn't know this way of doing it in the views. Seems way simpler than doing it in forms.py actually, even if i'm gonna use it in multiples views. Thanks.