# Copy current form data into new form using django

Tags: django, forms

I have two views, PostCreateView and PostUpdateView. They both route through the same html template, post_form.html. I want to create a Copy button that only appears if I am accessing a record through PostUpdateView. Pressing the Copy button will create a new record pre-filled with all the data from record that I was just on.

PostCreateView code:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'trucking/post_form.html'
    form_class = RecordForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.save()
        messages.success(self.request, f'RECORD: {obj.container_no} was saved')
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.request.POST.get('Save_Exit'):
            return reverse('close')
        elif self.request.POST.get('Save'):
            return reverse('post-create')
        else:
            return reverse('database')
```

PostUpdateView code:

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = RecordForm
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        history = Post.objects.filter(id = self.object.id).first().history.all().reverse()
        data['history'] = get_status_changes(history)
        return data

    # checks to make sure the user is logged in
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        messages.success(self.request, f'RECORD: {obj.container_no} was updated')
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.request.POST.get('Save_Exit'):
            return reverse('close')
            # return render(self.request, 'trucking/email_close.html')
        elif self.request.POST.get('Save'):
            return reverse('post-update', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})
        else:
            return reverse('database')
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245448/django-can-i-pre-fill-forms-with-a-model-instance-datas-in-form-py) I tried creating a view like so:

```
def copy(request):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk = request.users.post.id)
    my_form = RecordForm(instance = post)
    return render(request, 'trucking/post_form.html', {'form': my_form})
```

However, I get an error saying 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'users'. I think that's not the only issue with this approach.

Should it be a part of PostUpdateView, since it takes the form information from an existing record? Should it be part of PostCreateView since you take the preexisting info and fill out a new form with it? Should it be a new view altogether? Any help is appreciated

Comment: It's `request.user` not `request.users` if you are trying to access the currently logged in user.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not trying to access the currently logged in user. I'm trying to access the id of the currently filled-in form, which is based on the "Post" model. That's why I said that's not the only problem with this approach.